# how to fix the rondom generator in python ? Whenever I run my CNN I get different result

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train and test a CNN model for classification and every time I run the code in testing I get different accuracy results.

How can I get the same result every time? is there any possible solution in python TensorFlow for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you provide a sample of your code that is causing the issue?

Comment: probably `np.random.seed(0)` in the beginning of your file. But without code it's difficult for us to guess.

Comment: Does the model use dropout or image augmentation?

Comment: how different? training a DNN is not a deterministic process so there is always some randomness involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
```

The value you set the seed to is not important as long as you keep it fixed.

Make sure you also fix the seed for any third party library. Randomness can also caused by GPU-libraries, if you don't use GPU's don't worry about it.

**Edit**: Assuming you use TensorFlow as backend. For PyTorch (works for CPU and GPU btw) use:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(1)
```